# PHP - формирование списка из SQL-запроса

Tags: php, mysql, список

Есть MySQL-таблица, допустим, с 10 столбцами, имеющими названия а1, а1, ...., а10.
Значения в них записываются 1 или 0.

Мне нужно делать запрос к этой таблице, получать одну строку и формировать список неких слов, у которых значение = 1.

Например, строка с id=2 имеет значения [а1, ......, а10]: 1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0

- Слово 1 = а1
- Слово 2 = а2
- ......
- Слово 10 = а10

Мне нужно получить список вида:

- Слово 1
- Слово 2
- Слово 4
- Слово 9

Использую следующий код, но пока получаю null:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = 2";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
    
    $words = [
        'a1' => 'Слово 1',
        'a2' => 'Слово 2',
        'a3' => 'Слово 3',
        'a4' => 'Слово 4',
        'a5' => 'Слово 5',
        'a6' => 'Слово 6',
        'a7' => 'Слово 7',
        'a8' => 'Слово 8',
        'a9' => 'Слово 9',
        'a10' => 'Слово 10',
    ]; 

    $rrr =  "";
        foreach($words as $key => $value){
            if(isset($$key)) {
                $rrr .= "- $value<br>"; 
            }
        }
    };

print($rrr); // выводит пустую строку :(
```

Чего-то в коде не хватает...

Comment: *Есть MySQL-таблица, допустим, с 10 столбцами, имеющими названия а1, а2, ...., а10.* Настоятельно рекомендую нормализовать эту фигню. Способ нормализации? если действительно речь о значениях только 0 или 1 - отлично подойдёт тип данных SET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример с использованием PDO (настоятельно Вам рекомендую)
Файл подключения к БД `dbconnect.php`

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbname;host=localhost;charset=utf8', 'name', 'password');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Основной файл `main.php`

```
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php'; // Подключение к БД
$words = [
    'a1' => 'Слово 1',
    'a2' => 'Слово 2',
    'a3' => 'Слово 3',
    'a4' => 'Слово 4',
    'a5' => 'Слово 5',
    'a6' => 'Слово 6',
    'a7' => 'Слово 7',
    'a8' => 'Слово 8',
    'a9' => 'Слово 9',
    'a10' => 'Слово 10',
];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM temp";
$req = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$req->execute();
$array = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$rrr = '';

foreach ($array as $arr){
    foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $words)) { // ищем ключ в массиве
            if($value == '1') { // Проверяем равно ли значение единице
                $rrr .= '-' . $words[$key] . '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r($rrr);
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Все получилось.
Условие if (array_key_exists($key, $words)), в принципе, не обязательное, если 100% структура БД не будет меняться.